# Missing signatures on transaction 3CA098 for keys:-- by signers: com.template.contracts.IOUContract.Create

Tags: java, corda

My Contract class  where Create class is declared, do i have to write something in create class also?new to corda so if anyone have any references,Tutorials,Examples for learning corda with "Java" kindly share in the comments plus already completed Key Concepts from the Doc. Thanks in advance

````
```

    package com.template.contracts;

    import com.template.states.IOUState;
    import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandData;
    import net.corda.core.contracts.Contract;
    import net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction;
    import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandWithParties;
    import net.corda.core.identity.Party;

    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;


    import static net.corda.core.contracts.ContractsDSL.requireSingleCommand;

    // ************
    // * Contract *
    // ************
    public class IOUContract implements Contract {
        // This is used to identify our contract when building a transaction.
        public static final String ID = "com.template.contracts.IOUContract";

        //our Create Command
        public static class Create implements CommandData{

        }

        // A transaction is valid if the verify() function of the contract of all the transaction's input and output states
        // does not throw an exception.
        @Override
        public void verify(LedgerTransaction tx) {
            final CommandWithParties<IOUContract.Create> command =requireSingleCommand(tx.getCommands(),IOUContract.Create.class);

            //Constraints on the shape of the transaction

            if(!tx.getInputs().isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No inputs should be consumed when issuisng an IOU.");
            if(!(tx.getOutputs().size()==1))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("There should be one output state of type IOUState.");

            //IOU-specific constraints.
            final IOUState  output =tx.outputsOfType(IOUState.class).get(0);
            final Party lender = output.getLender();
            final Party borrower =output.getBorrower();
            if(output.getValue()<=0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("This IOU's value must be non-negative");
            if(lender.equals(borrower))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The lender and the borrower cannot be same entity");

            //Constraints on the signers.
            final List<PublicKey> requiredSigners =command.getSigners();
            final List<PublicKey> exceptedSigners =Arrays.asList(borrower.getOwningKey(),lender.getOwningKey());
            if(requiredSigners.size() !=  2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("There must be two signers");
            if(!(requiredSigners.containsAll(exceptedSigners)))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The borrower and lender must be signers.");
        }

        // Used to indicate the transaction's intent.
        public interface Commands extends CommandData {
            class Action implements Commands {}
        }
```
````

Reference:

```
Followed the link:- "https://docs.corda.r3.com/tut-two-party-contract.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside your state contract you set the validation rules. For instance, on `Create` both the borrower and the lender must be required signers: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/contract/IOUContract.java#L46
2. Inside your flow when you assign the command to the transaction, you must specify who are the required signers (it should match what your contract expects): https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L91
3. Assuming the initiating node of the flow is the lender, the node signs the transaction: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L106
4. In the responder flow, the borrower also signs the transaction: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L150

This way you collected both signatures.